# C# to Word Changing the value of Paragraph

Tags: c#, interop

I decided to Open a Word document, using Word Interop, in my background worker, which is called after MyForm_Shown(). And Closes it after MyForm_FormClosed().

I have button that saves the changes in the open Word document. The problem is when I changed or gave a new text/Value to my paragraph(oPara1), which is declared:

```
oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

It does not overwrite the previous value, rather adds the new value to the next paragraph.
How can I replace or set new value for a declared paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the text of a range look at the **Replacing Text in a Range** section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx) where the selected `Range.Text = "new text goes here"`.

Regarding your code snippet note that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraphs.add%28v=office.14%29) for Paragraphs.Add states that "The new paragraph doesn't replace the range" so I assume you'd have to [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.delete%28v=office.14%29) the Range at some point before setting the new text to `oPara1` paragraph if the above link doesn't help.